# How to set data rate in case of MAC/Tdma in ns2?

Tags: tcl, ns2, wifi

As we can set data rate for MAC/802_11 in ns2, can we do the same with TDMA? If yes please explain how? If we can't do it, please explain why not it is possible.

Comment: To get better answers, you may need to put additional effort into your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set basic rate and data rate for 802_11.

```
Mac/802_11 set basicRate_ 1Mb
Mac/802_11 set dataRate_  11Mb
```

For Mac/Tdma it is possible to set bandwidth.

```
Mac/Tdma set bandwidth_ xx
```